# why am i getting infinity for an answer

Tags: java, output, infinity

so, I've tried multiple different things, but I am still getting an answer of infinity when I run this for the last output, what do you think tht the problem is? The first output works fine, but the second and third do not. he exponent is supposed to be `^12*5`. Am i not doing the `math.pow` right?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class CompoundInterest { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        double principal = 0; 
        double rate = 0; 
        double time = 0; 

        double one = 0; 
        double three = 0;
        double five = 0;
        double a, b;
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of the loan: "); 
        a = input.nextDouble(); 

        System.out.print("Enter the Rate of interest : "); 
        b = input.nextDouble(); 

        one = a * Math.pow((1 + b/12),Math.pow(12,1)); 
        three = a * Math.pow((1 + b/12),Math.pow(12,1)); 
        five = a * Math.pow((1 + b/12),Math.pow(12,5)); 

        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("The Compound Interest after 1 year is : " 
        + one); 

        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("The Compound Interest after 3 years is : " 
        + three); 

        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("The Compound Interest after 5 years is : " 
        + five); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `To the power of 12*5`. Why not just do `^60`?

Answer (score 4):

You are actually taking two powers, for example in the second line (the one for five years interest):

`five = a * Math.pow((1 + b/12),Math.pow(12,5));`

which comes down to: `a * (1 + b/12)^(12^5)`. This is a number close to infinity on normal 32 or 64 bit computers.

Try using `a * Math.pow((1 + b/12), 12 * years);` where `years` is the number of interest years.

Answer (score 1):

You are raising something to the power of `12^5`, with is absurdly huge and should result in infinity.

Try

```
five = a * Math.pow((1 + b/12), 12*5);
```

instead.

Comment: This yields a number. [Here](http://ideone.com/W0wYy3) is the link to the IDEOne.